# Random access a file using File Channel?

Tags: java, file-io, nio, filechannel

When I get `FileChannel` from `FileInputStream`, I found I can use position method to freely move file pointer. Does it mean `FileChannel` provides the functionality of `RandomAccessFile`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's got some of the functionality, this is what [`RandomAccessFile.getChannel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) returns:

> The position of the returned channel will always be equal to this object's file-pointer offset as returned by the `getFilePointer` method.